# VS Code Test Explorer run button not working for tests in a Class

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, testing, pytest

When using Test Explorer in VS Code in a remote docker container (in MacOS Monterey M1), I am unable to run the individual tests that are within a Class from the buttons shown here:

[image: screenshot of vscode with icons that appear when hovering over files in the sidebar circled]

When I click on the Run Test button on the parent class (e.g. `AppointmentAdminTest` in the above image) it works just fine. The tests are included in the container through a volume pointed to my local file system.

Another oddity is clicking on the "Go To Test" button works for the class, but not the individual tests in the class. For example, in the screenshot, if I click on the "Go To Test" button for the `AppointmentAdminTest` class, it properly opens `/code/tests/test_admin.py` (`/code/` is the mounted volume path in the docker container), but when I click on "Go To Test" for an individual test within a class, it tries to open the file at the local path (`/Users/*my-username*/.../tests/test_admin.py`)

My pytest configuration is as follows:

```
"python.testing.pytestArgs": [
    ".",
    "--no-cov",
    "-v",
    "-s",
    "--rootdir",
    "/code/"
]
```

Comment: Whether the re-imported file is valid? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-python#_add-docker-files-to-the-project

Comment: I am using the container in VSCode by attaching to an existing running container (with the "Remote-Containers: Attach to Running Container.." command) and not using the remote explorer, so I don't think that article applies.  The files are visible and editable through the VSCode File Explorer, and it finds/opens the files just fine for the test files and the classes in the test files, just not the individual tests within the test file classes

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem (not sure if it's your case but maybe it'll help someone reading this).

I had to clear the pycache folder(s) and re-discover the tests (the reload/refresh button at the top).

Had to do that for each test folder but it all works now.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I had the reverse of OP's problem: wanted to view/run test outside of a container, but at some point had a container in the mix and VSCode kept trying to find tests in the container. Like OP, it worked at the "file" level but not for individual tests.

Removing the relevant __pycache__ directory and rediscovering tests fixed it 